# filter listView data using SimpleAdapter

Tags: android

i am using simpleAdapter to display names in a listView. i want to add a edittext widget to allow the user to filter for the name they want to find. however, i do not know how to do this. can someone explain how i can do this. here is my code:

```
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.HashMap;
   import java.util.jar.Attributes.Name;

   import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
   import org.json.JSONArray;
   import org.json.JSONException;
   import org.json.JSONObject;

   import android.app.Dialog;
   import android.app.ListActivity;
   import android.app.ProgressDialog;
   import android.os.AsyncTask;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.text.Editable;
   import android.text.TextWatcher;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.AdapterView;
   import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
   import android.widget.EditText;
   import android.widget.ListAdapter;
   import android.widget.ListView;
   import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
   import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
   import android.widget.TextView;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   public class Patients extends ListActivity{

  private static final String ID = "id";
  private static final String NAME = "name";
  private static final String PATIENTS = "patients";


  private ProgressDialog dialog;

      private EditText search; 

   //URL to get the patient info
   private static final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/HMS2/patients.php";

   ListAdapter adapter;

    //for getting the parse  data
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();


   // patients JSON ARRAY 
   JSONArray patients = null;

  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> patientsList;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.all_patients);

    search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    new LoadPatients().execute();

    //selecting single listView
    ListView list = getListView();

    list.isTextFilterEnabled();

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                long id) {

            String name = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
        }

    });

} 

 class LoadPatients extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
  {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(Patients.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading patients info...");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        //HashMap for ListView
        patientsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


        ArrayList<NameValuePair> query = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        //gets the JSON object 
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL, query, "POST");

        Log.e("error",json.toString());

        try 
          {
            //gets the JSON array which is patients 
            patients = json.getJSONArray(PATIENTS);

            //loop through the JSON array
            for(int x= 0; x < patients.length(); x++)
             {
                //gets the  key=> value position 
                JSONObject key = patients.getJSONObject(x);

                //gets the id value 
                int value = key.getInt(ID);
                String id = Integer.toString(value);

                //gets the name value
                String name = key.getString(NAME);

                //put the key => value in a HashMap
                map.put(NAME,  name);
                map.put(ID, id);

                //add the HashMap values to the ArrayList
                patientsList.add(map);

             }
          }
        catch (JSONException e) 
         {  
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
         }


        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
     {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

          //dismiss the dialog after getting all products
          dialog.dismiss();


          adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(),patientsList,R.layout.list_item,
                        new String[]{NAME}, new int[]{R.id.name});

          setListAdapter(adapter);              

        }


     }

    }
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html - you should look at this

Answer (score 0):

The best way is probably to add a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to the EditText widget, and then make use of the [Filterable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable.html) interface, implemented by SimpleAdapter. This can be kind of a pain to do though, so you may find it easier to just handle the filtering yourself, by creating a new list for your adapter, and as the user types, set the values in that list to the values in the original list which match the search query. Each time you update the list your adapter uses, you'll want to invalidate the data, so the list will be recreated.

Comment: so there is no other easier way to do this ?

Comment: Which part in particular are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Chris: `SimpleAdapter` already implements `Filterable`, so the extension of such an adapter can just override the relevant methods.

Comment: can u give me an example of doing this i  am  new to android development

Comment: @MH: Good catch, I didn't notice that before. My answer has been updated to reflect that. Thanks.